# Mobile responsive theme css not working

Tags: css, mobile, browser, web, responsive

I created this website: http://www.articaclima.it/home

As you can see, by resizing the browser window the mobile responsive css theme is working quite good.

Anywhere, by toggling device toolbar in the browser, or by viewing it in a mobile browser, the mobile css theme is not showing at all.

What could the problem be?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add Meta Viewport tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

your website is missing this.

Hope this Helps..

Comment: Hi Chandra, I already added it (into the createHead function). I tried anyway to add to the head, but is still not working.

Comment: add it before the script tag in the head and give a try

Comment: add script tags at the end of your page, just before closing of body tag.

Comment: Not working. What do you mean to add script tags just before closing of body tag?

Comment: your web page contains script tags in the head section, move them into the body tag.

Comment: The scripts in the head are ok: without them the slider is not working.

Comment: Beyond this, the problem is that yesterday the website was working responsively, but today no.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that into , dynamically generated via JS: there was an "user-scalable=0".